# http requests not working on Kotlin in AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, httprequest

I have a problem in Kotlin in Android Studio.
HTTP requests are not working for me and I have tried Fuel and Volley libraries for it.
I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` line in AndroidManifest.xlm file.

Volley code:

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "http://drevo.kybernado.com/app/get_count.php?code=200528-0961"

        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "That didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })

        queue.add(stringRequest)
```

Fuel code:

```
Fuel.get("http://drevo.kybernado.com/app/get_count.php?code=200528-0961")
            .response { request, response, result ->
                println(request)
                println(response)
                Toast.makeText(this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val (bytes, error) = result
                Toast.makeText(this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                if (bytes != null) {
                    println("[response bytes] ${String(bytes)}")
                    Toast.makeText(this, String(bytes), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
```

In volley it always gets an error and in Fuel there is no sign of activity - no toaster pops up.
Do you know why is it acting like this?
Thanks

PS: I'm new to Kotlin and Android Studio, but not in programming.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use this one [RetrofitApi](https://gist.github.com/Barros9/e97cd73b336b51f0154f222f0795c7d6) without coroutines, where your BASE_URL is "http://drevo.kybernado.com/app/" and yours GET_VALUE is "get_count.php" and add a code param in the interface `fun get(@Query("code") code: String): Call<String>`, you should pass this param in the get invoke `Api.retrofitService.get("200528-0961").enqueue( object: Callback<String>`